# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Given a variable `@myVariable` of type `BIGINT` and a `myColumn` of type `nvarchar(200)` from `myTable` this fails:

```
WHILE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE LEFT(CONVERT(bigint,myColumn),17) = @myVariable))
```

with the error in the title :

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Full query looks like that:

```
DECLARE @myVariable BIGINT
SET @myVariable = (SELECT CurrentNumber FROM MyNumbers)
WHILE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE LEFT(CONVERT(bigint,myColumn),17) = @myVariable))
BEGIN
    SET @myVariable = @myVariable + 1
END
```

I also tried this with `CAST(myColumn as BIGINT)`, but it fails also.

Comment: I bet that error is telling you that you have a non-numeric value returned and you are attempting an illegal cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not make sense:

```
LEFT(CONVERT(bigint, myColumn),17) = @myVariable
```

Why would you be calling a string function on a number?  Perhaps you intend:

```
CONVERT(bigint, LEFT(myColumn, 17)) = @myVariable
```

Regardless, I think you should pass in a string.  Assuming that `myColumn` is a string.  Somethinglike:

```
myColumn LIKE @myVariable + '%'
```

Of course, you could still pass in a number and use:

```
myColumn LIKE convert(varchar(255), @myVariable) + '%'
```

But I recommend using compatible types.

Leading zeros could pose an issue.  However, you have not provided sample data, so I don't know if that is an issue.

Comment: myColumn is always a number with 18 digits. Leading 0's cannot happen. I tried it like your second one, still the same error. I will update with a test case.

Comment: @Yuropoor . . . Change the type of the variable -- which you presumably have more control over -- to match the type of the column.

Comment: I tried your last approach and it works fine, thank you.